# GCP VPN Tunnel is up, I can see Sent Bytes, but traffic is not reaching the recipient

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, site-to-site-vpn, vpc-peering, google-cloud-vpn

I am trying to establish a VPN tunnel between a Classic CPN gateway and an on-prem VPN gateway. A requirement for the on-prem gateway is that traffic coming out of my VPN must present as a public external IP address (not a private IP address).

I am able to establish the tunnel using the public IP address of the VM. I am also able to route traffic from the VM to the Cloud VPN using a routing rule.

I can see quite a bit of "Sent Bytes", when I ping the remote server. This corresponds to when I send the PING requests.

However, no traffic is reaching the recipient.

So to summarize,

- The tunnel is up and running
- I can route traffic into the VPN so it shows Sent Bytes
- Traffic is not reaching the recipient

Comment: Is there any chance to share the brand and software level of the appliance on-site?

Comment: @ArdenSmith - unknown, but it is some sort of Juniper device